# Cannot convert from Decimal to Int32

Tags: c#, oracle

Could anyone be so kind as to tell me why, when reading from an Oracle database, I get the following error:

```
Object of type 'System.Decimal' cannot be converted to type 'System.Int32'.
```

It happens when I pass a variable (**oValue**) of type **object** into a function. I've tried casts, converts, unchecking, truncating, pretty much the whole sha-bang, and nothing works. Here's where the code fails:

```
PropertyInfo property = Objects[0].GetType().GetProperty(sProperty);
property.SetValue(Objects[0], oValue, null);
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

EDIT: Here's what I've tried so far:

`(int)oValue`, `Convert.ToInt32(oValue)`, `Math.Truncate((decimal)ovalue)`, `Decimal.Truncate((decimal)oValue)`, `Decimal.ToInt32((decimal)oValue)`, and using `unchecked {}`

Comment: Could you please post the variations where you've tried casting?

Comment: Gladly, I'll edit the question now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put:-

```
property.SetValue(Objects[0],Decimal.ToInt32(Convert.ToDecimal(oValue)) , null);
```

Comment: From this, I get `Specified cast is not valid.`

Comment: It is indeed, thanks very much! Any ideas as to why it was this ridiculously annoying?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yht2cx7b(v=vs.80).aspx , the second point discusses about this issue.

Answer (score 1):

As the property expects an `Int32` you shouldn't pass a `Double` value to it.

A boxed value can only be unboxed to the exact same type, so unbox it, convert to an integer and box it:

```
oValue = (int)((Decimal)oValue);
```

If you can make the value an `Int32` from start that would of course be better.

Answer (score 0):

you have stored procedure oracle with integer type and you pass a parameters of type decimal in your code Ado.net.

You can convert your parameter value

```
decimal value = ...;
int convertedValue = Convert.ToInt32(value);
```